# PHP: Updating database "num_views" of an image with id "x"

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like to increment a page views ("num_views") database value when a certain image in "Paging.php" is clicked on so I can keep track of how many times that image has been viewed

Paging.php:

```
while ($imageCounter < $imagesPerPage && ($row = $catResult->fetch_assoc())) {
    echo    "<br />ID: " . $row['imgid'] . 
            '<br /><a href="./templates/viewcomic.php?views='. $row['num_views'].'&id=' . $row['imgid'] . '&image=' . $imgpath.$row['imgname'] . '"><img src="' . $thumbpath.$row['imgthumb'] . '"/></a>' . 
            "<br />CATFK: " . $row['catfk'] . 
            "<br/>";

    $imageCounter++;
}
```

ViewComic.php

```
<?php
include 'include/header.php';

$imgid = $_GET['id']; 
$views = $_GET['views'];

include '../scripts/dbconnect.php'; 
$mysqli->query("UPDATE child_images SET num_views = ($views+1) WHERE imgid = $imgid");
mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
```

It doesn't seem to be incrementing though

Comment: nice... `example.com?id=10&views=50 kajillion`.  or better yet `...&views='); DROP TABLE Students;--`. That'll go over well. Enjoy having your server pwn3d, then go read about up (SQL injection vulnerabilities](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: While the solutions all work - none of them take into consideration SQL injections.

Comment: @MarcB lol marc, I'm a noob still. I won't be making that mistake again!

Comment: Please do not use `mysql_query` in new applications. Even this short snippet of code creates a gigantic [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/php) in your application. PDO or `mysqli` are considerably safer and easier to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An easier way is to just increment the value that has been posted into the database. This way you don't have to worry about data manipulate in your query string.

```
$imgid= $mysqli->real_escape_string($imgid);    
$mysqli->query("UPDATE child_images SET num_views = num_views + 1 WHERE imgid = $imgid");
mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

Comment: This one suffers from the same problem as the other in terms of sql injection.  See my comments on Rene's answer.

Comment: I do understand - however part of this community is helping people grow as programmers.  This is all just my opinion.

Comment: Please add `mysql_real_escape_string` to this answer.

Comment: FYI - since Growler is using mysqli you need to use the `mysqli_real_escape_string` function.

Answer (score 2):

Just do this:

```
$mysqli->query("UPDATE child_images SET num_views = (num_views+1) WHERE imgid = $imgid");
```

Comment: lol wow... how did I miss that... O_O... Btw, will it be costly/laggy to make a db update each time someone clicks on an image?

Comment: While this solution is "correct" it is a huge security flaw.  Simple changes can include using $mysqli->prepare() and bind_param().  Also adding an if(is_numeric($imgid)) around the query will also help.